# Adding Custom Headers in Kafka Message

Tags: apache-kafka

I am sending a file as a message by converting it to a byte array using kafka producer.

I also need to add some headers for the message, for example file name, timestamps etc so at the consumer end I can process the message based on file name and other headers.

What I am currently doing is creating a object and wrapping the raw message and headers in it and sending the object in a byte array as a message.

I would like to know if there is a way by which I can add custom headers while publishing the message?

Comment: please consider to accept answer provided by @Michal Borowiecki, to avoid confusion for those who looking for similar solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka is agnostic to the message content  <strike>and doesn't provide any special means to enrich it so this is something you need to do yourself. A common way of dealing with these things is to use a structured format such as json, avro or similar where you are free to define the necessary fields and could easily add metadata to your message and ship it off to the Kafka brokers.</strike>

This answer is outdated as of Kafka 0.11, please see other answers.

Comment: so in that case i will get all the message in entire topic and then parse each message and then based on my metadata apply some logic,i thought there will be a way by which i can get message consisting of some specific metadata instead of all message

Comment: This answer is out-of-date.   Headers have been supported in Kafka for years now.

Comment: This answer is out of date see other answears.

Answer (score 69):

Kafka v0.11.0.0 adds support for custom headers.

You can add them when creating a ProducerRecord like this:

new ProducerRecord(key, value, *headers*, ...), where headers is of type Iterable<Header>

For more details see:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4208

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers

Comment: Please demonstrate how this solves the problem in the answer itself.

Answer (score 25):

Record level headers were introduced from Kafka 0.11.0. We can send a list of Headers in each record.

```
List<Header> headers = Arrays.asList(new RecordHeader("header_key", "header_value".getBytes()));
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", null, "key", "value", headers);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own small java application to send the message with headers to kafka.
Write the following code in intellij or any supporting IDE:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, 
InterruptedException {
  Properties props=new Properties();       
  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
  JsonSerializer.class.getName());
  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonSerializer.class.getName());

  KafkaProducer<String, JsonNode> producer=new KafkaProducer<String, JsonNode>(props);
  String json = "{ \"f1\" : \"v1\" } ";
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
  ProducerRecord<String,JsonNode> record =new ProducerRecord<String, 
  JsonNode>("test topic", jsonNode);
  record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("key","value1".getBytes()));
  producer.send(record);
  Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

String json = "{ \"f1\" : \"v1\" } "- this is the key and value we want to send to kafka using objectMapper and converting it into jsonNode form.
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader("key","value1".getBytes()))-This is the key and value of headers data that we are sending to kafka.
To verify your data you can check the topic in the kafka control center and verify the headers sent.

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("bizops", "value"); 

producerRecord.headers().add("client-id", "2334".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
producerRecord.headers().add("data-file", "incoming-data.txt".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

// Details left out for clarity
producer.send(producerRecord);
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/5-things-every-kafka-developer-should-know/#adding-headers

Answer (score -1):

I've been through similar problems with projects I've worked on so I created this simple library to help tackle that: https://github.com/leandronunes85/messaging. For now contains an Avro based implementation but it can be extended to use any other serialization framework of your choice.

You just have to create a (de)serializer for the objects you want to have on the stream (Avro based or not) and let AvroMessageSerializer work its magic.

This is still a very young library but I feel it can save many people a lot of time!

Comment: Repo is (at time of writing) 5 to 7 years out of date and has been superseded by Kafka itself supporting headers.