# How can we version message in Kafka pub/sub?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have one problem about using Apache Kafka with details below.

I build 3 instances of one service has their own local cache called S1, S2, S3.
Example, when the update request come to the S1, S1 will update itself local cache then push a job to Kafka to update local cache for S2, S3. 
In this case I just want to S2, S3 get the job only, but in real when I use Kafka for pub/sub all S1, S2, S3 will get the job.

So how can I deal with this problem, any advise will be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options:

1. When the update request come put it to kafka and update cache only by consumed messages.
2. You can add meta-information to kafka-key and filter messages by that key.
   For example:
   key:instanceName=S1,
   if currentInstanceName != instanceName do_job

NOTE: key is used in partitioner - hashCode of key/round robin(depends on kafka version), so behavior can change.

3. Wrap you kafka message and add meta-information to wrapper. For example, if you use json:

   ```
   {
      "instanceName":"S1",
      "request":{...}
   }
   ```

Comment: could you please provide me the way to add meta information in java?

Comment: I found that kafka message cant add header here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025627/adding-custom-headers-in-kafka-message

Comment: Kafka header = kafka Key(updated). It's part of java API, see http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html, ProducerRecord.key